# Iterator requirements for a fake container supporting C++11 range-based for

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Around a year ago, I wrote [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20995782/180247) where I suggested an idea to replace deeply nested loops with a single iterable virtual-container object that "contains" all the indices.

The following is an implementation, but I'm still not that familiar with C++11 at the moment, so I thought I'd ask for a review.

Key points are...

1. Although this seems to work in GCC, that doesn't necessarily mean I've implemented all the interfaces I need for an iterator - what have I missed?
2. I wasn't confident about all the parameter-passing choices - where to use rvalue references, or lvalue references, pass-by-value, or letting the classes generate default methods. Have I made bad choices? Is it OK to pass `std::initializer_list` by value? Should `loopnest_state` have copy/move constructors and assignments?
3. The "elements" in the "container" obviously don't really exist. Instead, each iterator contains a `unique_ptr` to a computed element value - the `unique_ptr` is null for end. The computed element value is mutated when the iterator is incremented, so it still references the same object, just with a new state. Is this sensible? Should I try to avoid the extra heap allocation, get rid of the `unique_ptr`, and build the computed value into the iterator?

Anything else is welcome.

```
class loopnest;
class loopnest_iterator;
class loopnest_state;

class loopnest_state
{
  friend class loopnest_iterator;

  private:
    const std::vector<unsigned> &m_counts;
          std::vector<unsigned>  m_indices;

    unsigned m_depth;

    bool step_next ()
    {
      m_depth = m_indices.size ();

      while (m_depth > 0)
      {
        m_depth--;

        unsigned &l_index (m_indices [m_depth]);

        l_index++;
        if (l_index != m_counts [m_depth])  return true;
        l_index = 0UL;
      }

      return false;
    }

  public:
    loopnest_state (const std::vector<unsigned> &p_counts,
                    const std::vector<unsigned> &p_indices,
                          unsigned               p_depth   )
      : m_counts (p_counts), m_indices (p_indices), m_depth (p_depth)
    {
    }

    loopnest_state (const std::vector<unsigned>  &p_counts,
                          std::vector<unsigned> &&p_indices,
                          unsigned                p_depth   )
      : m_counts (p_counts), m_indices (std::move (p_indices)), m_depth (p_depth)
    {
    }

    unsigned Outermost_Changed () const  {  return (~m_depth ? m_depth : 0);  }
    unsigned Inc_Depth         () const  {  return m_depth;  }
    unsigned Nest_Depth        () const  {  return m_counts.size ();  }

    const std::vector<unsigned> &Indices () const  {  return m_indices;  }

    unsigned size       ()           const  {  return m_indices.size ();  }
    unsigned operator[] (unsigned p) const  {  return m_indices [p];  }

    bool is_first () const  {  return m_depth == ~0UL;  }

    bool operator== (const loopnest_state &p)
    {
      if (m_depth != p.m_depth) return false;
      if (m_depth == ~0UL)  return true;

      for (unsigned i = 0UL; i < m_indices.size (); ++i)
      {
        if (m_indices [i] != p.m_indices [i])  return false;
      }

      return true;
    }

    bool operator!= (const loopnest_state &p)
    {
      return !operator== (p);
    }
};

class loopnest_iterator
{
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<loopnest_state> m_state;

  public:
    loopnest_iterator ()
    {
    }

    loopnest_iterator (std::unique_ptr<loopnest_state> &&p_state)
      : m_state (std::move (p_state))
    {
    }

    loopnest_iterator (loopnest_state *p_state)
      : m_state (p_state)
    {
    }

    void operator++ ()
    {
      if (m_state && !((*m_state).step_next ()))  m_state = nullptr;
    }

    bool operator== (const loopnest_iterator &p) const
    {
      if (m_state == p.m_state)  return true;
      if ((!m_state) || (!p.m_state))  return false;
      return m_state->operator== (*p.m_state);
    }

    bool operator!= (const loopnest_iterator &p) const
    {
      return !operator== (p);
    }

    const loopnest_state &operator*  () const  {  return *m_state;  }
};

class loopnest
{
  public:
    typedef loopnest_iterator const_iterator;

  private:
    std::vector<unsigned>  m_counts;

    //  If any count is zero, there are no cases to iterate over.
    bool begin_is_end () const
    {
      bool l_Result = false;

      for (auto i : m_counts)
      {
        if (i == 0)  l_Result = true;
      }

      return l_Result;
    }

  public:
    loopnest ()  {}

    loopnest (std::vector<unsigned> p_counts)
      : m_counts (std::move (p_counts))
    {
    }

    loopnest (std::vector<unsigned> &&p_counts)
      : m_counts (std::move (p_counts))
    {
    }

    loopnest (std::initializer_list<unsigned> p_counts)
      : m_counts (p_counts)
    {
    }

    const_iterator begin () const
    {
      if (begin_is_end ())  return const_iterator ();
      return const_iterator (new loopnest_state (m_counts, std::vector<unsigned> (m_counts.size (), 0UL), ~0UL));
    }

    const_iterator end () const
    {
      return const_iterator ();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There are standard requirements for class to satisfy iterator model. They are needed to your class to be guaranteed to operate with stl and stl-compatible algorithms. But if you just need it to work in range-based for loop, your implementation is enough. Even operator== is not needed.
2. Initializer list is ok to pass by value, because it is just a pair of pointers or something similar. R-value references are mostly used in move constructors and assigments. In other cases just use copy instead of these functions:

   `loopnest (std::vector<unsigned> &&p_counts)`

   `loopnest_iterator (std::unique_ptr<loopnest_state> &&p_state)`

   `loopnest_state (const std::vector<unsigned>  &p_counts,
                         std::vector<unsigned> &&p_indices,
                         unsigned                p_depth   )`

   Caller will deside if he is ok with copy or move: `loopnest(counts)` / `loopnest(move(counts))`

   Copy/move assignments are useful for classes with resources. `loopnest_state` have resources in form of vectors. But vectors are good at managing their resources, so compiler-defined constructors/assigments will suffice. Just be aware of some compilers are old enough to not to generate move constructors/assigments.
3. In C++ classes have value semantics, which means instances fully can be held on the stack or as memeber in memory occuppied by another instance. This is preffered way and pointers should only be used in situations where heap allocation / indirection is inevitable. So yes, element should be direct member of iterator, not an `unique_ptr`.

Other observations.

I'm not sure user will need counts inside loop, consider return just indices from iterator.

There is still allocation (and, hence, indirection) in `loopnest_state` in form of vectors. Vectors are needed for a user to be able to created arbitrary-depth loops. The same result can be achived with touples, but it will require some heavy variadic metaprogramming.

Comment: The `vector` is needed for the actual use I finally decided to write it for, where the depth of nesting isn't known until runtime. I spotted a silly mistake in that `loopnest_state::operator==` etc aren't marked `const`, though `loopnest_iterator::operator==` etc are marked `const`. That suggests `loopnest_iterator::operator==` must be making a temporary copy of the `loopnest_state` instance, though I haven't checked. The reason for the `unique_ptr` was to avoid having the vector etc in the `end` iterator. But it does seem likely to be a pessimization.

Comment: Personally, my style preference is more towards using a single iterator that knows when it's exhausted unless you really need to pick an arbitrary position as the end of your iteration, but c++ iterators are a generalization of pointers not the OOP pattern - which is a slight pain sometimes when you don't really have an element to point to.

Comment: Those functions with the rvalue references *are* constructors, and meant to move-construct all or some part of an instance - e.g. the `loopnest_iterator` constructor gets it's `loopnest_state` instance from a temporary that `loopnest::begin` creates purely to initialize it. The extra `loopnest` constructors (beyond the initializer list) though are probably badly judged - for initializing from existing containers it should probably accept `begin` and `end` iterators (any container type) and (optionally) a lambda to extract the counts.

Comment: If the depth is not known at runtime, vector indeed is the choice, but I can hardly imagine such a situation. In initial stackoverflow question person wanted to get rid from deep nested loops, this implies depth is known in compile time.

Comment: Functions with r-values are constructors, but they are not "move constructors", ie do not move from instance of the same type. Those types already know how to move themselves,  pass them by value is enough.

Comment: @GeniousIsme - that was OPs requirement. Mine is in a code generator, and I need to generate all cases (for a variable number of arguments) where each argument can be in one of several forms. So I transform the vector of parameter-specifications into a vector of counts, use that `loopnest` class to do the iteration, and in the loop use the indices to determine the current case for each parameter - there's still an additional layer of loop nesting for the parameters, but only one. The initializer list constructor was for testing and because this is a learning exercise too.